# Что дороже для DVM/ART? Сравнение с null или Nullable Object?

Tags: android, производительность, dalvik

Что дороже для сравнения по ссылке - с null или с заранее проинициализированным статик объектом (который по совместительством является Nullable Object) в java при работе со скомпилированным кодом для Dalvik VM/ART?

Если на примере то вот, например одна часть модели:

```
public class Device {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("identifier")
    private String imei;
    @SerializedName("given_at")
    private long givenAt;
    @SerializedName("phone_number") 
    private String devicePhoneNumber;

    public Device(final int id, final String imei, final long givenAt, final String devicePhoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imei = imei;
        this.givenAt = givenAt;
        this.devicePhoneNumber = devicePhoneNumber;
    }

    public int getId() {
        if (id == 0)
            return NULLABLE_ID;
        else
            return id;
    }

    public String getImei() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imei))
            return NULLABLE_IMEI;
         else
            return imei;
    }

    public long getGivenAt() {
        if (givenAt == 0L)
            return NULLABLE_GIVEN_AT;
        else
            return givenAt;
    }

    public String getDevicePhoneNumber() {
        return devicePhoneNumber;
    }

    public boolean isGiven() {
        return givenAt != NULLABLE_GIVEN_AT;
    }

    public static final class NullableDevice extends Device {

        public static final int NULLABLE_ID = -1;
        public static final String NULLABLE_IMEI = "empty";
        public static final long NULLABLE_GIVEN_AT = -1L;
        public static final String NULLABLE_PHONE_NUM = "empty";

        public static final Device instance = new NullableDevice();

        private NullableDevice() {
            super(NULLABLE_ID, NULLABLE_IMEI, NULLABLE_GIVEN_AT, NULLABLE_PHONE_NUM);
        }
    }
```

На текущий момент проблем не испытваю, но задаюсь вопросом, так как есть большой список с большим количеством элементом и громоздкой логикой, часть которой является проверка на null (сервер может не вернуть то или иное значение для модели, а от этого зависит логика отображения и бизнес логика)

Comment: Что именно вы подразумеваете под сравнением с объектом? Сравнение "==" будет очень дешевой операцией, вызов equals() для двух объектов в теории более дорогая операция, так как подразумевает вызов метода (хотя, опять же в теории, компилятор может заоптимизировать вызов). НО, важно то, что это будет в любом случае несущественно, и оптимизации такого уровня вряд ли имеют практический смысл.

Comment: Последнее ваше замечание - бесспорно. Меня интересует что дешевле val == null или val = NullableDevice.instance.NULLABLE_VALUE, где во втором случае объект заранее проинициализирован

Comment: Даже по длине записи понятно что `val == null` дешевле. Он выполнится в одну инструкцию `if_equal_zero`. Во втором случае добавятся два чтения полей в регистры. Но это всё мелочи - Вы же не собираетесь обрабатывать гигабайты json'ов!?

Comment: @woesss ни в коем случае. Просто интересно, не более того. Просто мне кажется для точного ответа нужно хорошо ращбираться в байткоде, в том как работает dvm/art, чем я похвастаться, к сожалению, не могу

Comment: На самом деле Ваш код до рантайма пройдёт ещё несколько уровней оптимизации, и как он выполнится в конечном счёте, наверное и сами разработчики VM подвиснут в ответе ))) Но в одном я уверен - что это сравнение будет далеко не самым узким местом в Вашем приложении.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, это не ваше дело. Вы пишите на языке, которого на целевой платформе НЕТ ВООБЩЕ (что было доказано в затянувшемся суде). Ваша задача - написать код, а что будет дальше - не ваше дело.

Но человеку всегда интересно, что же там происходит под капотом, всегда охота стать экспертом. Окей. Берем апктул или даже родной дэикс из родного СДК и декомпиляем то, что получилось. Смотрим. Между прочим, еще в процессе компиляции, один и тот же код может скомпилироваться сильно по разному, а потом еще dx может дополнительно его оптимизировать. Или не оптимизировать - у него есть и такая опция. А потом может прибежать какой-то протектор и насовать мусора. Или оптимизатор и повырезать лишнее. Причем такой протектор-оптимизатор может работать как с готовым DEX, так и еще с JVM-кодом, как это делаем всем нам знакомый ProGuard. И вот только после всего этого, наш код попадает в APK. Но на этом путешествие нашего кода не заканчивается. В принципе, пока был dalvik, этот код уже мог бы выполнятся сразу, а мог и оптимизироваться до odex при инсталляции и выполняться уже он. Если посмотреть код dalvik, то можно слегка испугаться и понять, что сравнивать количество опкодов - некорректно, да и версий интерпретатора может быть множество. Но мир пошел другим путем и Далвик теперь является лишь историей. Теперь же, во времена ART, весь этот замечательный код полностью перекомпилируется в нативный и что там будет в итоге - предсказать крайне сложно, особенно если мы начали свое путешествие из высокоуровнего языка, который перенес столько трансформаций.

Лично мой выбор - сокращение кода, поэтому лесенки в коде, на мой взгляд - это всегда плохо. Да и сложно будет постоянно проверять, в наличии у нас истинная строка, или ее затычка, что может привести к лесенкам кода уже в других местах. И это, на мой взгляд, еще хуже. Так что, чистые истинные данные - мой выбор. Но с другой стороны, вдруг нам надо просто насрать кое-как этими данными в единственную вьюху, да еще и наверняка склеить несколько значений в единое целое - зачем городить огород и раскладывать все по полочкам, если это никому не надо, а можно сразу пачку полей передать как единое поле?

А если хочется выдрочить каждый опкод, то добро пожаловать в прекраснейший мир JNI, где код компиляется сразу в байткод целевой платформы, где нету промежуточных компиляторов и оптимизаторов, где программисты контролируют всё и вся, являясь при этом богами. Но быть богом - это большая ответственность, многие просто не смогут забраться на этот уровень. Да и не нужно это в современном мире, все равно приложение показывающее одну картинку может выжрать гигабайт памяти, для отображения анимированной гифки мы открываем инстанс браузера (WebView), а партнерские модули воруют приватные данные - это все давно стало нормой жизни и встречается в каждом втором приложении, деньги текут рекой, люди все радостные.

А вообще, вот такой выбор путей - это и есть работа программиста

Comment: Вы написали, как по мне так, ответ, содержащий больше эмоций и философии нежели информации, так как она, скажем так, поверхностно понятна большинству. Но судя по всему вы разбираетесь в этом вопросе, возможно, лучше чем я и буду рад если вы поделитесь ссылками или источниками информации которые были бы полезны, если я вдруг захочу попытаться писать что то более серьезное чем "формошлепство".

Comment: Будучи носителем знания, как я считаю, я вполне имею право оформить его в том виде, в котором считаю нужным. Источники: книги о компиляции, к примеру Денис Юричев со своей книгой beginners.re, касательно непосредственно Андроида - это описание его байткода. Практические задания: чтение исходников Дальвика, декомпиляция других приложений (я выкачивал сотни приложений только ради последующего разбора), написание своего софта для манипуляций.